# ParseException while trying to parse string timestamp

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I am trying to parse a timestamp with a `SimpleDateFormat` but it raises `ParseException` in Java 1.8. The same code works flawlessly in Java 9 or higher. The example code snippet

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
public class TestStrftime{

     public static void main(String []args) throws ParseException {
        String TS_FMT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TS_FMT);
        String szSableTimeStamp = "2020-01-16T19:32:13.540000Z";
        Instant sableTimestamp = dateFormat
                        .parse(szSableTimeStamp)
                        .toInstant().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(sableTimestamp);
     }
}
```

and it raises the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2020-01-16T19:32:13.540000Z"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at TestStrftime.main(TestStrftime.java:12)
```

but with Java 9 or higher, its able to parse the date with the desired output

`2020-01-16T19:41:13Z`

Comment: Why not use `DateTimeFormatter`?

Comment: Tried to reproduce with mave plugin set to 1.8. Worked fine. Anything else in your env that could cause the problem?
```
       <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it help of you explicitly call out the zulu on the end ?
```"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX'Z'"```

Comment: @Keynan You can also reproduce in https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/ and setting jdk to 1.8.
> Out of curiosity, does it help of you explicitly call out the zulu on the end ? "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX'Z'"
No, tried on jdoodle without any success.

Comment: Java 9: How could `2020-01-16T19:41:13Z` be the desired output from parsing `2020-01-16T19:32:13.540000Z`?? It’s 8 and a half minutes off.

Comment: As a compete aside, the variable name `szSableTimeStamp` seems to be wrong. Some C++ guidelines say to use `sz` at prefix for zero terminated strings. But Java strings are not zero terminated.

Comment: @OleV.V. Since `SimpleDateTime` only supports *milliseconds*, the `SSS` parses `540000` as 540000 milliseconds = 540 seconds = 9 minutes, causing `19:32:13.540000` to become `19:41:13.000000`. Any value other than *exactly 3 digits* after the decimal point will always be parsed wrong by the old API, e.g. `19:32:13.54` would be parsed as `54` milliseconds, not `540` milliseconds.

Comment: @Keynan Having both `XXX` and `'Z'` wouldn't work. *Replacing* `XXX` with `'Z'` would make the parsing work like Java 9+, i.e. it would still **parse incorrectly** ([9 minutes off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59807717/parseexception-while-trying-to-parse-string-timestamp/59807911#comment105755443_59807717)), but wouldn't throw exception.

Comment: In any case I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). (where also `Instant` and `ChronoUnit` come from)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant                             // The modern way to represent a moment in UTC. Resolves to nanoseconds.
.parse(                             // Parse text in standard ISO 8601 format without specifying any formatting pattern.
    "2020-01-16T19:32:13.540000Z"
)                                   // Returns an `Instant` object.
.truncatedTo(                       // Lop off part of the data.
    ChronoUnit.SECONDS              // Keep whole seconds and larger. Lose the fractional second, if any.
)                                   // Returns a new fresh second `Instant` object, per immutable objects pattern. Original `Instant` is left unaffected.
.toString()                         // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/gptgkP).

> 2020-01-16T19:32:13Z

## Details

You are mixing the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `SimpleDateFormat` with their modern replacements. Do not do this. **Use only classes from the *java.time* packages.**

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class knows how to parse strings in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format such as your input string. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2020-01-16T19:32:13.540000Z" ;  // Using standard ISO 8601 format.
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;      // By default parses ISO 8601 strings. No need to specify a formatting pattern.
```

If you want to drop any fractional second, [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

```
Instant instantWholeSeconds = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

Generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format by calling [`Instant::toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#toString()).

```
String output = instantWholeSeconds.toString() ;  // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

If you want a count of seconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of the first moment of 1970 in UTC, interrogate the `Instant` object by calling [`getEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#getEpochSecond()).

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = instant.getEpochSecond() ;
```

> am trying to parse a timestamp with a SimpleDateFormat

Never use `SimpleDateFormat` again. Obsolete with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The legacy date-time classes are a bloody awful mess. Avoid them like the plague.

Answer (score 4):

The issue with `SSSXXX` not matching `540000Z` was fixed by [JDK-8072099: Format "ha" is unable to parse hours 10-12](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072099) in Java 9.

The real issue is that `SSS` represents **millisecond**, while `540000` is *microseconds*, so even the Java 9 parser gets it wrong by parsing that to 9 minutes (540 seconds).

Since you want an `Instant` object, do not use the old flawed `SimpleDateFormat`. Use `DateTimeFormatter` instead:

```
String TS_FMT = "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX";
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(TS_FMT);
String szSableTimeStamp = "2020-01-16T19:32:13.540000Z";
Instant sableTimestamp = Instant.from(dateFormat.parse(szSableTimeStamp))
                .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(sableTimestamp);
```

However, since your format happens to match the ISO-8601 format, which is the natural format of an `Instant`, just use the [`Instant.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) method, without any need for a formatter:

```
String szSableTimeStamp = "2020-01-16T19:32:13.540000Z";
Instant sableTimestamp = Instant.parse(szSableTimeStamp)
                .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(sableTimestamp);
```

Comment: Thank you. Yours is a complete answer but unfortunately I already accepted an answer.

Comment: @Abhijit You can change which answer you accept, if you want to. Basil's answer is good too, so accept the one you prefer, but up-vote both ;-)

Comment: I know, just a courtesy I don't want to change. But I can give you a bounty but for that you have to wait.

Comment: @Abhijit No need, we both have adequate rep, don't need a boost. I'm good with Basil's answer being the accepted one.